# SQLite Insert statement in Android;

Tags: android, sqlite

The following is the declaration statement of a SQLite table I wrote;

```
db.execSQL("create table if not exists data( d text, hr integer, rrInterval real, acc_x real, acc_y real, acc_z real);");
```

So this is what the table `data` looks like.

```
data{
    d text,
    hr integer,
    rrInterval real,
    acc_x real,
    acc_y real,
    acc_z real
}
```

And I got some variable measured with Microsoft Band 2, stored in the following variables; I checked all these variables get the proper data from MS Band.

```
String d;
int heartRate;
double rrInterval;
float acc_x, acc_y, acc_z;
```

So this one is for storing the data in SQLite database.

```
MyOpenHelper helper = new MyOpenHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

db.execSQL("create table if not exists data( d text, hr integer, rrInterval real, acc_x real, acc_y real, acc_z real);");


/* some other codes irrelevant to DB */

db.execSQL("insert into data(d, hr, rrInterval, acc_x, acc_y, acc_z) values ('" +
    d + "', " +                               //date
    Integer.toString(heartRate) + ", " +      //hr
    Double.toString(rrInterval)+ ", " +       //rrInterval
    Float.toString(acc_x) + ", " +            //acc_x
    Float.toString(acc_y) + ", " +            //acc_y
    Float.toString(acc_z) +                   //acc_z
    ");");
```

As far as I know there is no syntax error both on Java and SQLite. But Android Studio returns error, which is not that `insert ...` statement. How can I figure out how to solve this problem?

Comment: `" But Android Studio returns error"` what error does it return? why dont you use `SQLiteDatabase#insert()` method?

Comment: your code works fine for me .I am using Android Studio 2.3.2

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using that kind of approach try to use ContentValues its much easier to use.

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("d", DATA_NEEDED_TO_INSERT);
cv.put("hr", DATA_NEEDED_TO_INSERT);
cv.put("rrInterval", DATA_NEEDED_TO_INSERT);
cv.put("acc_x", DATA_NEEDED_TO_INSERT);
cv.put("acc_y", DATA_NEEDED_TO_INSERT);
cv.put("acc_z", DATA_NEEDED_TO_INSERT);
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv); // insert function
db.close(); // dont forget to close your db
```

dont forget to db.close(); after the process cheers

Comment: this code doesnot compile: there is no `SQLiteDatabase#put()` method

Comment: sorry my bad i change it to insert